# How does one prove that $n^{-100} = \omega(2^{\sqrt{\log{n}}})$?

Tags: asymptotics

I feel that $2^{\sqrt{\log{n}}}$ could be dramatically simplified, but I'm sure how. Aside from plugging in huge values to test the functions, any ideas on how I can prove this relationship?

Comment: You can write $n^{-100}=e^{-100 \log n}$, and $2^{\sqrt{\log n}}=e^{\log 2 \sqrt{\log n}}$; does that help?  (And are you missing a minus sign somewhere?  Otherwise $n^{-100}\rightarrow 0$ and $2^{\sqrt{\log n}}\rightarrow \infty$ is sufficient.)